# Is it a bad idea to store my Firebase ref as a static variable?

Tags: android, firebase

Is there some benefit to using activity member variables for the Firebase ref instead? I was thinking GC and thus the connection to the Firebase severs would be kept open, so that may be a bad thing?

Comment: Yes, keeping the firebase connection open is of course a bad thing. Firebase creates a web socket to trigger the changes. So for Android, its a battery draining issue. Why do you need to keep a static reference to a firebase reference anyway?

Comment: @ReazMurshed that's what I figured :\ but I was hoping maybe some Firebase socket management magic was going on behind the scenes where it wouldn't matter. But I wanted to keep a static reference because I felt like I was typing the same thing over and over again. But I guess I could use a static method that builds me the Firebase location string for me

Comment: Yes you can have a static string to store the location string for Firebase reference, but, keeping a static reference is not ideal I guess.

Comment: @ReazMurshed that sounds like a great answer! Keeping a static variable like that bypasses the Android lifecycle models, which in general is indeed not a good thing.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your compliment. I saw your answers about firebase all over the SO. So this compliment from you meant a lot for me. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. But it wasn't just a compliment, it was also a call-to-action. If you provide it as an answer, I can upvote it. :-)